# Get h4 element text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

[First of all, please understand that I will post to you by translator.]

Clicking button class "LEARN MORE, I want to get the text of the `<h4>` element:

[image]

Comment: Post *code/markup*, not *pictures* of code/markup. More: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/157247

Comment: I have no idea what you need. What is your question? What have you tried? What is the expected vs. actual result?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this

```js
    $("a.btn").click(function(event){
        event.stopPropagation();
        event.preventDefault();
       console.log($(event.currentTarget).closest("td").find("h4.title").text());
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <h4 class="title">Test</h4>
      <a class="btn" >Click me</a>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

just add this in script tag under header tag.(u need the Jquery script library to use jquery functions).

```
$(".btn-red").click(function(){

   console.log($("h4.item-title").text());

});
```

Comment: just add this in script tag under header tag.(u need the Jquery script library to use jquery functions).